# how can jqGrid paging number in query

Tags: spring, oracle, jsp, jqgrid

i use jqGrid.
Data in the 10000 pieces. so jqGrid rendering is very slow.
my idea is page number in query.
query is success.
but i don't know jqGrid option.
grid reload on paging 'next' or 'prev' click . and page number change for example  +1 or -1.
how can i pager value in jqGrid option.
i have a pager.java (int currentpage, totalPage, rowlist, totalRows)
and this is code Call from a parent Grid cell.

//-------

```
> $("#detailList").jqGrid({         datatype: "json",       mtype:"post",
>       colNames:[ .....],
>       colModel:[ ...... ],
>       gridview: true, 
>       rowNum:-1,
>       sortname: 'route',
>       viewrecords: true,
>       autowidth:true,
>       rownumbers:true,
>       loadonce:true,
>       sortorder: "asc",
>               jsonReader:{
>           repeatitems:false,
>           root:"detailList",
>           id:'0'
>       },
>       loadComplete:function(){
>           var rows = $(this).getGridParam('records'),
>               $t   = $('#'+$(this).attr('id')+'Rows');
>           $t.text(rows);
>       }       }); //.navGrid('#detailListPager',
```

> {add:false,del:false,edit:false,search:false});
>
> $("#detailList").setGridParam({           url:'url',          datatype:"json",
>             //page: 1,          postData: {
>                 va1.va1,
>                 va:$("#va").val(),
>                 listNumber:1000,
>                 pageNo:1            }       }).trigger("reloadGrid");

Answer (score 0):

can you please show your code, how you are doing things.
meantime you can have a look on this

`$("#table_id").setGridParam({
                    datatype: 'json',
                    page: 1,
                    url: 'xyz.htm'
                }).trigger('reloadGrid');`

have a look on this : http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/help/using-client-side-sorting-but-server-side-paging-using-jqgrid

it will help you for sure.

Comment: you are missing onPaging event and also set $("#table_id").setGridParam({datatype:'local'}); in oncomplete event.

Comment: also make sure you are using compatible version for jquery and jqgrid.